# Files from Yeoman web-app that needs to be committed in SCM/GIT

Tags: version-control, gruntjs, yeoman, bower, yeoman-generator

When we do "yo webapp" (assuming webapp generator is installed), it scaffold projects which contains file relevant to bower, grunt and then there is app folder, which we all know what's it about.

My question is, out of this structure what are the files that needs to be maintained in SCM, Should it be only app directory or should it whole structure ?(assuming there are no additional grunt task or any build file changes from earlier scaffolding)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Yeoman* [webapp generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp) will produce a  `.gitignore` file which includes files that should not be committed to a SCM. This file includes the following directories:

```
node_modules
dist
.tmp
.sass-cache
bower_components
test/bower_components
```

It is clear that `.tmp` and `.sass-cache` have no reason to be in the repo as they both are only temporary.

There is however a [discussion](http://addyosmani.com/blog/checking-in-front-end-dependencies/) whether *bower* (and rarely *node*) dependencies should be checked in. For most projects I recommend not to.

Please note that in either case one **should never** change the packages directly in the `bower_components` or `node_modules` folder as any change will be lost at next `bower install` or `npm install`. A fork of the original project (either as a independent repo or to folder in the project - e.g. `lib`) is a better idea - a follow up pull request would then add a lot of karma :)

The `dist` folder with the build of the application may be committed depending on your deployment method.  There is a very good guide on [deployment on Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/deployment.html) site.

Answer (score 1):

As a start, you should put everything into SCM with the exception of app/bower_components, test/bower_components and node_modules. All files under these directories come from public repo, either node or bower repo.

In this setup, whenever another developer checkout from SCM, he needs to run 2 commands: npm install and bower install. What I typically do is I create a file called install.sh (install.bat on Windows) and have these 2 commands inside this script file. In this way, when you find that you need to run more commands for initialization, you can easily add to this script file and new developers can just checkout and run install.sh.

In some cases, I found that I need to perform small modification to a public library. In this case, I will check this library inside bower_components into SCM as well. This is not common, but it happens.